# How can I justify combining the limit of a limit into a single limit?

Tags: analysis, limits

I'm trying to prove this formula for the second derivative of a $f:\, \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$:

$$
  \begin{align*}
      f''(a) &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f'(a)-f'(a-h)}{h}  \\
             &=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\lim_{h_1 \to 0} \frac{f(a+h_1)-f(a)}{h_1}-\lim_{h_2 \to 0} \frac{f(a-h+h_2)-f(a-h)}{h_2}}{h_2} \\
             &=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\lim_{k \to 0} \left( \frac{f(a+k)-f(a)}{k}-\frac{f(a-h+k)-f(a-h)}{k} \right )}{h_2} \\
             &=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}-\frac{f(a-h+h)-f(a-h)}{h}}{h} \\
             &= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-2f(a)+f(a-h)}{h^2} \\
  \end{align*}
$$

Eliminating the first limit was justified since $lim_{x \to c}\; (g + h) = lim_{x \to c}\; g + lim_{x \to c}\; h$, but how can I justify the elimination of the limit between lines three and four?

Comment: You can not justify the steps you are talking about as it is wrong. The formula for 2nd derivative can be proved using L'Hospital rule without much problem. I will let you proceed with this hint. In case you face any issue let me know. Also note that the formula is valid only when $f''(a)$ exists.

Comment: See the following question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/634885/72031